# How to get AWS cognito refresh token expiry?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, jwt

I have a scenario where I wanted to get expiry of AWS cognito refresh token. I am able to decode and get expiry of ID and access token. I am using AWS python lambda and jose to decode. Can anyone suggest me the way to decode it.

Comment: I cannot find a reference in the documentation, but refresh tokens are opaque values to the client and they cannot be decoded. I believe you'd only know a RT is expired when you try to exchange it for an access token (e.g. via `InitiateAuth`) and get an error.

Comment: Yes @MaxIvanov, but I wanted to check if there is any way we can get expiry time of RT before InitiateAuth.

Comment: I'm interested in the exact same thing @ABCD.  Anyone found a solution OTHER than testing for an error response against InitiateAuth with a refresh token that may or may not have expired.

Comment: I didn't found any workaround on that @tfrancois

Comment: FWIW if the refresh token came from your own user pool and code, you can just store the issuance time and compare it with the `RefreshTokenValidity` of the user pool client for an approximate value